# How to perform a stacked/element-wise matrix vector multiplication in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume we have a bunch of 3 by 3 matrices along with a bunch of 3-dimensional vectors:

```
N = 100
matrices = np.random.rand(N, 3, 3) # shape: (100, 3, 3)
vectors = np.random.rand(N, 3)     # shape: (100, 3)
```

How can I perform an "element-wise" matrix/vector multiplication, so that e.g. `result[0]` is the 3-dimensional vector resulting from the matrix/vector multiplication of `matrices[0]` with `vector[0]`.

Using `np.dot`, `np.matmul`, or `np.prod` directly fails due to the non-matching shapes. Is there a broadcasting trick to make this work?

Comment: This seems like a very basic question, which I expected to be on SO, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Divakar This is not a duplicate of the marked question, because the other question has the special constraint that it must not use `np.matmul` or `np.einsum`. I'm looking for the most basic standard solution without such specific constraints.

Comment: So, are you saying you don't need a solution with `einsum` or `matmul`?

Comment: @Divakar I'm fine with any solution, but the other question isn't. That's why it doesn't have an accepted answer. In fact the other answer answers my question but not the one it was written for ;).

Comment: No worries, added a better dup :)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.sum(matrices * vectors[:,:,None], axis=(0,1))
```

`None` adds a dummy axis to the vector that will match the third axis of `matrices`. The `einsum` method linked in the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5147920) seems faster:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ij->k', matrices, vectors)
```

Comment: Your initial version doesn't yield the expected result shape `(100, 3)`. What about: `result = np.matmul(matrices, vectors[:, :, None]).squeeze()`

Comment: @bluenote10 Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See the updated one.